# Reporting Rare Time-to-Event Data

Tags: poisson-regression, epidemiology, kaplan-meier, rare-events

I was recently given some registry data to evaluate time to new cancer diagnosis following transplant in about 8500 patients. The PI is interested in time-to-cancer differences based on various patient demographics (e.g., biological sex, obesity status, etc.) evaluated separately (at least initially).

In these data, the incidence rate of one specific cancer is 3% (about 250 of the 8500 patients), so 97% of patients are censored. It is my understanding that the Kaplan-Meier method is appropriate to use with rare event data. However, my data precludes observing the median time-to-cancer given the non-event rate will always be >50% and estimated mean time-to-cancer wouldn't be well defined given the largest observations are censored.

Considering the low incidence of this cancer, one of my colleagues suggested I select only the 250 patients who developed cancer and evaluate time-to-cancer differences between various demographics (e.g., biological sex) using a Poisson or, more likely, a negative binomial regression model. I argued with them for a bit stating any estimated difference would likely be biased given it excludes censored patients.

So, I'm at a bit of a loss on how and what to report for results. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Since you are dealing with demographic variables the affect surviival why wouldn't you use a Cox proportional hazards model or some generalizatio n of it.  If you use Kaplan-Meier wouldn't you be comparing several curves?  I think you have to convince the PI to use all the data.

Comment: continued: Leaving out the right censored patients would bias median survival.  It would be too short.

Comment: Sorry, my wording wasn't perfect. They want to initially consider each demographic separately. BTW, only biological sex was "statistically" significant. I agree with your PH model suggestion; although, I had already calculated relative risks and 95% CIs. With that said, I would expect the RR and HR to be similar, albeit with slightly different interpretations (i.e., cumulative vs. instantaneous). What I'm more concerned with is how to report the time-to-event data--over and above the result that women have greater risk--given that both the median and mean survival estimates would be biased.